# Delete function not working in Student database program using files

Tags: c, database, file

It creates the temp file containing the required result. but its not removing the previous file "records.txt" and not renaming temp.txt. im using dev c++.

```
void delete()
{
    FILE *fp, *ft;
    int no;
    char ch;
    student stud;

    fp = fopen("Records.txt","r");
    printf("\nEnter student's RollNo to delete:");

    scanf("%d",&no);
    ft = fopen("temp.txt","w+");

    while (!feof(fp))
    {
        fscanf(fp, "\n%d\t%s\t", &stud.roll_no, stud.name);
        if (stud.roll_no != no)
        {
            fprintf(ft, "\n\t%d \t%s", stud.roll_no, stud.name);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(ft);

    remove("Records.txt");
    rename("temp.txt","Records.txt");
}
```

Comment: First problem [`while(!feof(fp))` is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26557243/1983495). And you do absolutely no error check. Check every single possible error, and you will know why things didn't work, for example `remove()` returns `-1` on error, and sets `errno` so you can use `strerror()` and check what actually didn't work.

Comment: Looks like a school assignment... please do also use the "debugger", so that you can step through your code line by line. Your current code is also somewhat "risky", in the worst case, you could lose your records.txt file.

Comment: Thank you. yeah ill try doing what you told me to. :)

Comment: @iharob To be picky, those functions return a _non-zero_ value if they fail. So don't check `if(remove("...") == -1)` but rather something like `int failed = remove("..."); if(failed) { ...`